# Maximum concurrent sessions by default in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am developing a web application in Asp.net.
There is a possibility that almost 5,000 users can access my project at a time.
So I want to know what is the maximum numbers of concurrent session available in asp.net by default and if it's not enough to achieve my target how can I increase it.

Please help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is concurrent session in ASP, which can be found out from Site -> ASP (Double-Click) ... at the bottom expand session properties.

Also, there are concurrent connections set for each website which can be found by selecting the website and then selecting Advanced settings in the action pane. Then expand connection limits to read or modify those.

From : http://forums.iis.net/t/1163743.aspx?Maximum+Number+of+concurrent+sessions+

---

There is no limit on maximum concurrent session in asp.net...but to provide good support to end users you need to make use of following

1. Make use Of ajax
2. Make use of parallel library or threading
3. Your server machine should have good configuration in terms of memory and cpu speed
4. Make use of out of process session exaple in sql server

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but where will I find Site->Asp(Double-Click)....
I am using VS-2012

Comment: @ShaiwalTripathi - that might be found in IIS...you need to go to IIS and check..

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a web stress testing report to tell you how many concurrent sessions are available for your hosting SERVER.

If your concurrent user are way beyond your Server can handle, increasing available sessions won't do any help, you will need to scale-up your Server's hardware specification.

And `Load Balance` is a common solution for your case, you may think about it.

For reference : [How to find Concurrent Users using IIS Logs](https://altfo.wordpress.com/2013/04/07/how-to-find-concurrent-users-for-sharepoint-and-asp-net-using-iis-logs/)

Cheers.